# Variable bitrate streaming with Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: flash, video, streaming, amazon-web-services

Hey there - does anyone know what I need to do to set up variable bit-rate streaming with Amazon Cloudfront. I am not using JWPlayer but have built my own flash player.

What calls to I need to make to Cloudfront and how do I make them? Or is it all handled on the client side?

I am using FMS 3.5.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video player will have to make a call to FMS to switch the stream.

I'd suggest looking at the [RTMPMediaProvider swap function](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/RTMPMediaProvider.as#L583) as an example of how to do this. In short, your code would look like this:

```
var _stream:NetStream;
var nso:NetStreamPlayOptions = new NetStreamPlayOptions();
nso.streamName = getID(NEW_PATH);
nso.transition = NetStreamPlayTransitions.SWITCH;
_stream.play2(nso);
```

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video